# How to perform action on a specific number dial in android?

Tags: android, service, android-dialer

I want a service to monitor the calls I dial, and to perform a specific task parallel to a specific call.
Example. I call 123 from the dialer and a specific task gets triggered at that time.
But if I dial some other number then nothing should happen. 
How can I implement such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`

```
public class OutgoingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent. getAction (). equals (Intent. ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
       String number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER); 
       Log.e("Number=", number);

       if (number.equals("123")) {
       // do your magic here
       }   

      }
}
```

And don't forget and using permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```